# Проверка на возможность размещения рекламы в ВК (vk api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно понять предоставляет ли сообщество возможность размещения у себя рекламы с помощью VK API.

Смотрел методы:

Groups - возвращает все что угодно, кроме этого. Смотрел также методы в ADS - ничего тоже не нашел.

Как это сделать? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, рекламу внутри сообщества реализовывают администраторы сообщества самостоятельно (могут опубликовать рекламный пост). Об этом может быть написано в описании или в меню сообщества. В VK API узнать о такой возможности, нет.